# upload excel with APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY_B

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to upload an Excel file and display it in the collection through this code.

```
declare
l_query clob;

begin

l_query := 'select *  from
                   apex_application_temp_files f, table( apex_data_parser.parse(
                                    p_content                     => f.blob_content,
                                    p_file_name                   => f.filename,
                                     p_skip_rows => 1 ) ) p
                                      where   f.name = :P14_UPLOAD )';
                
     APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY_B (
         p_collection_name => 'IMPORT',
         p_query => l_query,
         p_truncate_if_exists => 'YES',
         p_names => apex_util.string_to_table('P14_UPLOAD'),
         p_values => apex_util.string_to_table(:P14_UPLOAD));
                      
                                    
end;
```

But I don't know where p_names => apex_util.string_to_table('P14_UPLOAD') and
p_values => apex_util.string_to_table(:P14_UPLOAD) What should I do to get the name of my file browser.

:P14_UPLOAD name file browser in page.

please help me. thanks.

Comment: What are 'b1' and '10' ? This procedure is for a query with bind variables. The query only has :P14_UPLOAD as bind variable. What is the relation of b1 and 10 with your query ?

Comment: b and 10 are examples of the collection. Instead of b and 10, I want P14_UPLOAD to be placed, but I don't know how to define it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah docs are not too clear on that. Try this:

```
declare
  l_query clob;
  l_names apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
  l_values apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
begin
  l_names(1) := 'UPLOAD';
  l_values(1) := :P14_UPLOAD;
  l_query := 'select *  from
                   apex_application_temp_files f, table( apex_data_parser.parse(
                                    p_content                     => f.blob_content,
                                    p_file_name                   => f.filename,
                                     p_skip_rows => 1 ) ) p
                                      where   f.name = :UPLOAD )';
                
     APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY_B (
         p_collection_name => 'IMPORT',
         p_query => l_query,
         p_truncate_if_exists => 'YES',
         p_names => l_names,
         p_values => l_values);
                                                      
end;
```

You can replace `l_values(1)` with a hardcoded value if you want.

Comment: I used your code but got the following error ORA-20104: create_collection_from_query_b Error:ORA-20104: create_collection_from_query ExecErr:ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BLOB

Comment: What if you use CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY instead with hardcoded values. Does that work ?

Comment: no I got same error.

Comment: Well... then it is not related to this question. The question was how to use bind variables - I answered how to do that. The issue you're getting now is that you're trying to insert a clob into a number.... No idea how to solve that for you, it would take me way too long to get a similar use case.
You could also check out a "data load wizard" to do the work for you. Then apex will set it up for you. It's a lot less work.